# why position fixed is not working on mobile screens?

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

This is only happening on the mobile versión, in the section underneath the lead video when I click them I'm applying the position fixed but its not making the element fixed, I'm thinking that maybe is because the position fixed is inside of a media query, but I don't know, I'm loosing my mind :( hahaha, if you can help me I will send you pictures of my dog.

https://monumento-studio.github.io/thrust/

Comment: Help us out here... add the relevant code to your question, make a demo, and clarify exactly what the problem is and what should be happening, thanks

Answer (score 0):

your z index value is low
try this

```
    #nav {
  position: fixed;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3.125rem;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 100;
}
```